# i want to convert into epoch(i.e) milliseconds

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

But I want to convert into milliseconds, my time stamp is like this in postgres sql

```
2013-05-14 14:03:28.675126
```

can any one tell the query i can convert up to

```
2013-05-14 14:03:28
```

this part in http://www.epochconverter.com/

my query is like this

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1315310331000/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second
```

but after .675126 that value also i want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
=> SELECT extract(epoch from now()) + 1315310331000/1000;
     ?column?     
------------------
 2686258457.90003
(1 row)
```

Comment: in my postgres sql the data type is timestamp without timezone is like this 2013-05-14 14:03:28.675126 i want to convert into epoch format,can u tell me?

Comment: If the above doesn't work, then I'm afraid I don't understand the problem.

Comment: my query is like this select branchId,branchCode,branchName,branchDataType,branchDataSize,uomid as branchUOMId,mbranch.status as branchStatus from mbranchwhere clientid=-1 and modifiedon=(SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1331663400000/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second')

Answer (score 0):

Do not divide. Multiply by milliseconds

```
select timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + 1315310331341 * interval '1 milliseconds';
          ?column?          
----------------------------
 2011-09-06 08:58:51.341-03
```

Comment: my timestamp is like this 2013-05-14 14:03:28.675126 how to convert into epoch or long